# Syntax Highlighting in Terminal for Python?

Tags: macos, python, terminal.app, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to turn on python syntax highlighting for Terminal.app on Mac OS X?

Comment: Do you mean inside the Python read-eval-print interpreter?

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to highlight sources you dump into the terminal a la `cat`
try excellent [pygments](http://pygments.org/). It actually supports a lot of languages. Run with

```
pygmentize source.py
```

If instead you were talking about editing files with syntax highlighting inside a mac terminal, this really depends on the editor.

- for `vi` or `vim` you want at least these option in `~/.vimrc`

  ```
  syntax on
  ```
- `emacs` works right out of the box
- don't ask me about `nano`.

Comment: `include "/usr/share/nano/python.nanorc"` - quite good.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`ptpython`](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython) in github, simply

```bsh
pip install ptpython
```

and use it with `ptpython`.

Answer (score 1):

Try ipython. It highlights syntax and much more. 
I haven't tried it on Mac but looks like it must work: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726449/installing-ipython-with-readline-on-the-mac
 
 
Another option is WxPython and pycrust (which works without Terminal.app :( )